# ODBC: Falló INSERT en la tabla vinculada

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

Tengo una duda respecto a access... Mi situación es la siguiente:
Tengo mi documento access con una tabla vinculada SQL, a parte tengo otra tabla con las mismas filas que la tabla vinculada. Mi idea era tan simple como que al pulsar un botón los registros de la tabla access se insertaran en la tabla vinculada como se puede ver en el código:

```vb
Private Sub Traspasar_Click()

Dim SQL As String

   SQL = "DELETE * FROM articulosinsert "
   CurrentDB.Execute(SQL)
   
   SQL = "INSERT INTO articulosinsert "
   SQL = SQL & "SELECT * FROM Final"
   CurrentDB.Execute (SQL)
   
MsgBox ("Proceso terminado.")
End Sub
```

El delete del principio está para que no se me repitan los registros cada vez que pulse el botón. El problema lo tengo al pulsar el botón que es cuando obtengo el error que he puesto en el título. (Haciendo pruebas he visto que el DELETE si que es capaz de ejecutarse, en cambio cuando pruebo con el insert me salta ese error). ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe o si se trata de algún error de sintaxis? Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT: He probado seleccionando los campos en el insert y tambien he probado con un recordset pero sigue saltando el mismo error.

```
rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not rst.EOF
        rst2.AddNew
        rst2.nId = rst.nId
        rst2.nIdEmpresa = rst.nIdEmpresa
        rst2.sCodigo = rst.sCodigo
        rst2.nIdProv = rst.nIdProv
        rst2.fAlta = rst.fAlta
        rst2.fBaja = rst.fBaja
        rst2.fModificado = rst.fModificado
        rst2.fEnviado = rst.fEnviado
        rst2.fRecibido = rst.fRecibido
        rst2.bLocal = rst.bLocal
        rst2.Update
    rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    rst2.Close
```

Comment: Las tablas son idénticas? Tienen alguna columna con autonumérico? Seria mejor no poner el asterisco, enumerando los campos `insert into tabla (campo1, campo2) Select campo1, campo2 from TablaOrigen`

Comment: si tu campo `nId` es autonumérico, no puedes. Tienes que especificar en qué campos quieres insertar valores, algo tipo `INSERT INTO articulosinsert ( EMPRESA, PRODUCTO ) SELECT Final.EMPRESA, Final.PRODUCTO
FROM Final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que las alternativas ofrecidas tampoco funcionaban correctamente. Opté por la opción de dejar el código VBA y crear una Consulta de Anexar. Luego en el botón añadí un procedimiento de macro para que abra esta consulta y anexe los resultados.
Es una solución simple pero cumple con el objetivo que era solo insertar los datos en la otra tabla. Muchas gracias a todos por su respuesta. Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]